# Как изменить тип столбца в миграции Laravel

Tags: laravel

Подскажите как изменить тип данных столбца с `varchar(255)` на `DATE` выполнив миграцию в Laravel

Comment: $table->date('column_name')->change();

Подробней на официальном сайте: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`' at line 1 (SQL: ALTER TABLE contract_pays CHANGE date date DATE CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`)

Comment: Покажите в каком виде у вас хранится дата в базе